# PHP Post fill text inside <input type="text">

Tags: php, post, text, input, fill

## [dominios/process.php](http://pastebin.com/qwSA6MmS)

This is a domain register script

Here's the output for an available domain, with a **Register** button next to it

```
echo
   '<h5 class="available">
       <span>Available</span>
       ' . $domain. '<b>' . $extension .'</b> is available!
    </h5>
   <a href="register-form.php">Register</a>';
```

That `<a href="register-form.php">Register</a>` should send register-form.php the chosen domain and extension informations, and fill it in the text input

### register-form.php

Formulary that holds the `<input id="domain" type="text" />` and that needs to be filled with the functions mentioned above /\ , with both domain and extension

Full process.php code available by clicking the title of this question, /\ above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can 'fill' your input field with `value="your value here"`

You can fill your input field server side with some GET variables like so: `value="<?php echo $variable;?>"`

Now it's up to you how you can get the register button to send a GET variable to the register form.php.

Try googling, as this is basic knowledge; and you need to show us *some* effort your self.

**edit** You can do it with a form as described above, but that's not the only way. You could change the link behind your 'register' text to `register-form.php?ext=domainA.com`:

```
echo
'<h5 class="available">
   <span>Available</span>
   ' . $domain. '<b>' . $extension .'</b> is available!
</h5>
<a href="register-form.php?ext='.$domain.$ext.'">Register</a>';
```

In your other page you should do something like:

```
$url = do_some_type_checkingAndChecks($_GET['ext']);
<input id="domain" type="text" value='<?php echo $url;?>'/>
```

Comment: It worked this way!

Guys, I know it looks like I didn't try to research and stuff, I've came across some topics similars to mine, but they were at the same time very different, but it is working now, i'll just try to block the edit form the text input now so the visitor can't change it, and it's done! Thanks for your time and effort, have a nice day!

Comment: Try to look into the `readonly` and `disabled` attributes of the `input` tag. Also make sure your code is not vulnerable to malicious code being transmitted!

Answer (score 1):

Since you're not using a [**form**](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html) - clicking the button will generate a simple redirect without POST parameters. If you want to pass values to your page, you should do something like:

```
echo   '<h5 class="available">
           <span>Available</span>
           <b>'.$domain . $extension . '</b> is available!
    </h5>
    <form action="register-form.php" method="GET">
    Domain: <input id="domain" type="text" value="' . $domain . $extension . '"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>';
```